# VTD XML (Java) VTDNavHuge write XPath result to file

Tags: java, xml, performance, vtd-xml

I am experimenting with VTD XML because I frequently need to modify huge XML files (2-10GB or more).

I am try to write an XPath Query result back to a file. 
Writing huge files in VTD XML is not obvious to me though:

1. The method getBytes() is "not implemented" for XMLMemMappedBuffer (see https://jar-download.com/javaDoc/com.ximpleware/vtd-xml/2.13/com/ximpleware/extended/XMLMemMappedBuffer.html)
2. One of the authors (?) gives a code example in this thread (last post, 2010-04-21): https://sourceforge.net/p/vtd-xml/discussion/379067/thread/a2e03ede/

However, the example is outdated as

```
long la = vnh.getElementFragment();
```

returns an Array long[] (see https://jar-download.com/java-documentation-javadoc.php?a=vtd-xml&g=com.ximpleware&v=2.13)

Adapting the relevant lines like this

```
long[] la = vnh.getElementFragment();
vnh.getXML().writeToFileOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:/text2.xml"), (int)la[0], (int)la[1]);
```

results in the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(Unknown Source)
    at com.ximpleware.extended.XMLMemMappedBuffer.writeToFileOutputStream(XMLMemMappedBuffer.java:104)
    at WriteXML.main(WriteXML.java:16)
```

Questions:

- Is this error due to any obvious mistake in the code?
- What tools would you use to handle huge XML files (~10GB)
  efficiently? (Does not have to be Java.)

My goal is to do simple
   transformations or split the xml and write back to file with great
   performance.  Thanks!

Comment: I think there was a bug that supposed to be have been fixed, it might have only checked into cvs

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer your first question, but as to the second, if you're looking for different technology then streaming XSLT 3.0 is one to explore: can't tell whether it's actually suitable without seeing more detail on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to process XML of huge size as you mentioned, I suggest that you load xml into memory using mem-map mode. And since vtd-xml doesn't alter the underlying byte format of xml, you can easily imagine saving a lot of back-and-forth encoding/decoding byte-moving operations and the performance advantage thereof.

As you have pointed out,  XMLMemMappedBuffer getBytes is not implemented... this is to avoid excessive memory usage when the fragment is very large...

your work around is to use XMLMemMappedBuffer's writeToFileOutputStream() method to directly dump it to output. In other words, if you know the offset and length of the fragment... getBytes is often bypass-able.

Below is the signature document of that method.

public void writeToFileOutputStream(java.io.FileOutputStream ost,
                                    long os,
                                    long len)
                             throws java.io.IOException
write the segment (denoted by its offset and length) into an output file stream

Comment: Thank you for your reply @vtd-xml-author. Could you help me understand why I get the above error? (BTW It would be great to find more up-to-date examples for VTDHuge on the VTD blog, especially examples that save some transformed output xml to file.)

Comment: can you put together a test case so I can do a bit digging on my end?